# Cant clone ssh/https to my mac from gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have had an issue with pushing/pulling changes to GitLab, so I decided to remove the git repository on my mac.

However, now it wont let me clone the project again.
I am met with various error messages and have tried everything to fix the problem, with no luck. I cant clone with either SSH or HHTPS.

I have now deleted my ssh-key and made a new one (I think) that I have connected to GitLab.

I will provide a picture *and text* with the error messages I get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J39g0.png]

```bash
marcus@Marcuss-MacBook-Pro-2 cd .git
marcus@Marcuss-MacBook-Pro-2 .git % git clone git@gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no:marcuslj/rentadog-git 
Cloning into 'rentadog'... 
ssh: connect to host gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

marcus@Marcuss-MacBook-Pro-2 .git git clone https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/marcuslj/rentadog.git 
Cloning into 'rentadog'...
Username for 'https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no: marcuslj
Password for 'https://marcuslj@gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/help/topics/git/troubleshooting.git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/marcuslj/rentadog.git/'
marcus@Marcuss-MacBook-Pro-2 git %
```

I first try with SSH, then HTTPS as you can see. None of them work.
Have already scattered all over the internet to try and find a solution, with no luck.

Now I am at the point where I just want to reinstall git completely, which I have also tried and didn't manage to do...

So anyways, if anyone could help me, that would be great.

Comment: Is your server listening for SSH connections on port 22? If yes, are you behind a firewall which blocks this traffic?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

While you might have a network/firewall issue preventing you to use SSH, HTTPS should work.

Make sure to create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), and use that as a password.

While you are at it, make sure the [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) is installed: that will help you to cache your credentials (username/token).
That way, you won't have to re-enter them again on each push.